# Adding and converting numbers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So far my program asks the user for a number and it to the total ( which in my case is set to 0 at the moment) the ask another number and adds them up.

```
        int userNumber;
        int total = 0;
        int i;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input == "e")
            System.Environment.Exit(1);

        else
            userNumber = Convert.ToInt32(input);

        Console.WriteLine("The running total is: " + total);

        for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter another number");
            userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            total = userNumber + total;
            Console.WriteLine("The running total is: " + total);
```

What I am trying to achieve is eg - in the first line user inputs '5', I want this to be the total, but I cant because total=0.

When I try to delete the 0 and do - `total=userNumber`  I get an error.
Any suggestions to get round this problem? thank you

Comment: "I get an error" shall we guess?

Comment: @TimSchmelter un assigned int variable compile time error

Comment: **To the Close Voters**: It is not an off topic question, it explains the whole scenario(what is current output, and what it should be) and shows what has been tried. It is a legal question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialise the value of `userNumber` before you can use it and, because the compiler can see a code path where if input is "e" then userNumber hasn't yet been assigned, it gives the error.

If you change the first line to this, it should compile fine:

```
int userNumber = 0;
```

You can simplify this, though, by just writing it like this instead:

```
int total = 0;
for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
   if (i == 0) // First time asking for a number
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
   else
       Console.WriteLine("Please enter another number");

   userNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   total = userNumber + total;
   Console.WriteLine("The running total is: " + total);
}
```